How to use http instead of https for identity server?
I am trying to configure the identity server to use http instead of https. I am currently trying to use the sitecore cli and running into an issue related to SSL. Error below.
"The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception."
Does anyone know how I might configure it to use http instead?
Thanks!

Sitecore Identity server works only under the HTTPS protocol. However, it can support SI clients under both HTTP and HTTPS as long as they are configured properly in the SI server configuration.
You can configure SI client inside the AllowedConfiguration section in the Config\production\Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml file.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Settings>
  <Sitecore>
    <IdentityServer>
      <Clients>
        <DefaultClient>
          ...
          <AllowedCorsOrigins>
            <AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>https://host1|http://host1</AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>
            <AllowedCorsOriginsGroup2>https://host2</AllowedCorsOriginsGroup2>
            <AllowedCorsOriginsGroup3>https://host3</AllowedCorsOriginsGroup3>
          </AllowedCorsOrigins>
          ...

You can find more details for the same here.
Hope this helps!!!
